# an open source lexicographical framework

Tags: computational-linguistics, dictionary, vocabulary, lexicography

I am looking for a lightweight open source framework for lexicographical experiments: building vocabularies, converting from one type to another, merging, dealing with multilingual issues, ...

google and github didn't show anything :). 
Any ideas?

p.s. As I understand WordNet, FrameNet and UNL are systems with prebuilt architecture and phylosophy.